# Как подключить ADB WIFI в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, wifi

Скачал плагин ADB WIFI для запуска приложения через WIFI. При нажатии на Tools, ADB to WIFI ничего не происходит. Как его подключить?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Если не пользоваться плагинами, которые будут работать через раз то можно и руками всё сделать. Там всего пара действий и плагин тут не очень нужен.

1. Подключаем девайс по USB
2. Открываем терминал в папке с `adb` по пути `ПУТЬ_ДО_SDK/sdk/platform-tools`
3. Убеждаемся что девайс и комп в одной `Wi-Fi` сети.
4. Набираем `adb tcpip 5555`
5. Набираем `adb connect IP_ДЕВАЙСА`

Далее, в 95% случаев достаточно выполнить лишь п5.

Comment: adb в большинстве случаев можно найти по 

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Android\sdk\platform-tools\adb

Answer (score 3):

Если вы про [этот](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB) плагин, то для того чтобы подключить устройство по wi-fi, его необходимо хотя бы раз подключить с помощью провода. Об этом сказано [здесь](https://github.com/pedrovgs/AndroidWiFiADB#usage).

Comment: я подключал через usb и нажимал как написано, но не реагирует.

Comment: @Cypher При подключении через usb Android Studio видела устройство?

Comment: да. я всегда через usb подключаю

Comment: @Cypher тогда стоит завести issue с указанием проблемы в репозиторий плагина

Answer (score 3):

Немного сейчас не так. Эта инструкция должна помочь.

4 шага:

1. Подключаем девайс по `USB`

   *В терминале*:
2. `cd C:\Users\mxsof\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`
3. `adb tcpip 5555`
4. `adb connect ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ_IP_ДЕВАЙСА:5555`

*Примечания*:

- Девайс и компьютер должны быть в одной `Wi-FI` сети.
- Как найти путь к `platform tools`: `Settings` > `вбиваем в поиск "android sdk"`, `копируем путь`, у меня это `C:\Users\mxsof\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk`, добавляем к пути `\platform-tools`.
- Посмотреть ваш `локальный ip-адрес` можно в настройках в разделе `о телефоне`, или воспользовавшись любым онлайн сервисом.

Answer (score 0):

Сейчас (в октябре 2020), проще всего получилось сделать через [вот этот plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/14969-adb-wi-fi).

Единственное, важно проверить, чтобы правильный путь к `adb` был указан.

Инструкции по использованию:

1. Подключите устройство через USB-кабель.
2. Откройте окно инструментов "ADB Wi-Fi" (в правом нижнем углу).
3. Нажмите кнопку "Подключить".
4. После успешного подключения можете отключить USB-кабель.